# The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValuekind or the object could not properly converted Registry.SetValue c#

Tags: c#, registry, regedit

I am using Winforms on .NET 4.5, I try to set registry value.

This is my code:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile", "NetworkThrottlingIndex", "ffffffff", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

and

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile", "NetworkThrottlingIndex", "0000000a", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

But this raised an error :

> The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValuekind or the object could not properly converted

Please help me fix this.

Comment: That Registry value is a DWORD, so why a string? BTW, you cannot set `uint.MaxValue` when the data type is DWORD, because uint is not CLS compliant. You'd have to use `RegistryValueKind.QWord`. Or PInvoke instead

Comment: i take the registry value form reg file here is original value in reg file:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile]
"NetworkThrottlingIndex"=dword:ffffffff , as you see dword is the type of value, but i will try to use QWord and see result

Comment: also here is original value from reg file: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile]
"NetworkThrottlingIndex"=dword:0000000a
so the type value is dword

Comment: Not being able to use `uint.MaxValue` as DWORD Registry value is a .NET, say, *limitation*. You were trying to use a string, though, instead of the actual `0xFFFFFFFF` value. If you really need to set that value, you may NOT want to change the data type to QWORD, it may have undesirable results. If that's the case, you may want to PInvoke instead

Comment: you right i must use 0xFFFFFFFF and 0x0000000a instead of string

Comment: it worked when using QWORD

Answer (score 1):

i have to use QWORD instead of DWord , and not using string but actual value :

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile", "NetworkThrottlingIndex", 0xFFFFFFFF, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile", "NetworkThrottlingIndex", 0x0000000a, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
```